# How to fix Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm getting "type 'Futture' is not a subtype of type '() => void' " error and just wondering how can I fix this error. Any suggestion or help will be really apprecaited.

```
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: _launchURL(),
                        child: Text(
                          'maxis@gm.com',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor),
                        ),
                      ),



  _launchURL() async {
    final url =
        Uri.encodeFull('mailto:smith@example.org?subject=News&body=New plugin');
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }


``
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass callback here:
from

```dart
onTap: _launchURL(),
```

to

```dart
onTap: () => _launchURL(),
// or
onTap: () {
    _launchUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe if you try to update

```
_launchURL() async {
```

to:

```
void _launchURL() async {
```

and

```
onTap: _launchURL,
```

for more details, check this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-curious-case-of-void-in-dart-f0535705e529)